# a system of finite difference equations

Tags: dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations, recurrence-relations

Let $a,b>0$ such that $ab<1$  consider the system$$x_{t+1}=x_ty_t+ay_t$$ $$y_{t+1}=x_ty_t+bx_t$$

I would like you to help me answer the following:

1. find values $a$ and $b$ ​​for which  the solution $\left(\frac{1-ab}{1+b},\frac{1-ab}{1+a}\right)$ is of saddle type
2. can one obtain the general solution explicitly?

any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" exactly?  Clearly, $x_t=y_t=0$ for all $t$ is a stable equilibrium for the system and I'm sure there's at least one more equilibrium, which might or might not be stable.  Do you mean more than this?

Comment: Right. I'll edit

Comment: Question 1. seems entirely within the standard framework. What is preventing you to solve it?

Comment: I just correct!

Comment: Say, which part of the accepted answer was eluding you when you posted the question? Since you never answered my previous comment, we have no way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the Jacobian matrix and put the solution (fixed point) to obtain

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}y & x+a \\ y+b & x\end{bmatrix} \vert_{\left(\frac{1-ab}{1+b},\frac{1-ab}{1+a}\right)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-ab}{1+a} & \frac{1+a}{1+b} \\ \frac{1+b}{1+a} & \frac{1-ab}{1+b}\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the fixed point is a saddle point if and only if $\text{det} J < 0$ (for 2nd order systems of course).

Finding an explicit solution might be difficult. However, the system equations itself is a recursive solution.